# How to retrieve an internal text

Tags: html, xml, xpath

How to retrieve `text` from this template using XPath?

```
<div class="c">
<span> a </span>
      text
</div>
```

I know that `//div[@class='c']//text()` returns whole `div` part, but I only want the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one slash too much. One slash makes sure that only text directly below `div` is returned:

```
//div[@class='c']/text()
```

The above returns text nodes. In many places in XPath or XQuery, they get automatically converted to strings (atomized), but you can also explicitly force a conversion to strings:

```
//div[@class='c']/text()/string()
```

or if you need to clean up for spaces and empty text nodes to return exactly `text`:

XPath 2.0:

```
//div[@class='c']/text()/normalize-space()[string-length() gt 0]
```

XPath 1.0 (for this specific document):

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='c']/text()[2])
```